# Gating a 5 V signal on <microsecond scale with a small gate signal, should I use a MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, gate-driving, analog-switch

I have a 20 Hz (~25 µs long) 5 V square-pulse that I would like to block most of the time, and only let through when another channel is above some 100 mV level. I wonder what would be suitable electronics for these voltages? I have previously used a MOSFET to switch 600 V with a 5 V trigger signal, but maybe there are some other components that are more suitable for these low voltages I now want to use.

Thanks for the answers, would this circuit work (modified from Simon)?
[image]

Comment: Use an AND gate for the pulse and a comparator on the other channel feeding the other input of the AND gate.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBX2Wl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

U1 is a comparator, whose inverting input is set to about 100mV by the potential divider consisting of R1 and R2. When the analogue input signal INA exceeds that threshold, its output goes high to 5V, but is otherwise low, at 0V.

IND is your pulse train. As long as the comparator output is low (INA < 100mV), OUT is also held low. If however the comparator output is high (INA > 100mA), the AND gate's output (OUT) will rise and fall with IND, essentially becoming a copy of IND.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It seems I have to use a comparator?

I was hoping to be able to block the signal with the MOSFET, but that seems to not work. Before I saw your answer I bought a https://docs.rs-online.com/c17b/0900766b80f9a390.pdf but the +5 V signal just goes thorugh the Source-Drain nomatte what I send in Gate

Comment: I managed to get the comparator to work. The R3 pull up resistor (I guess it's called) was rather important... However the component was also fluctuating quite allot and if I blew on the system it stoped working for a few seconds... The small format was really hard to solder so I've searched a bit extra and found the LM393 like @Simon suggested to begin with and orderred that, so hopefully it'll work better. 
Now I'm struggeling with the AND gate... where allot of the signal leaks thorugh when in the off-state and when the signal should come though there is a spike in the beginning...

Comment: Hello again @simon have a look at the video here (skip to 5:40 of the video for the part relevant to this thread):  https://www.ndt.net/search/docs.php3?id=26758 at

Comment: @MnM I watched the video, what are you asking?

Comment: sorry for being unclear I just wanted to thank you for the help! We have used your circuit and shown that is has potential to increase the saftey when using laser ultrasound. (You are also acknowledged in the bottom of the slide). Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @MnM Oh! Thanks, and you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Look for analog muxes or switches like Analog Devices ADG series.  They should be sufficiently fast.  NLASB3157 is another example mux from memory.  You can use a discrete fet but that has various gate drive challenges.

Though you’ll need a comparator to test for that 100mv level signal.

Comment: Ok, the ADG736BRMZ seems to be fast enough, I guess I could use that one as the U2 component in Simons diagram above.

Comment: Would this https://docs.rs-online.com/94a8/0900766b816e7361.pdf comparator work?